# Error occurred while loading a Visual force page. After when I hit save button

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com, developer

```
    <apex:page standardController="Product_Brief__c" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" extensions="SUM">
       <apex:form >
         <apex:pageBlock id="myPanel">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 1: Custom Media Information" collapsible="false" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Opportunity__r.Account.Name}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Customer_Number__c}" rendered="{!bEditMode}"/>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Customer_Number__c}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Billing_Address__c}" rendered="{!bEditMode}"/>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Billing_Address__c}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.CreatedBy.Name}"  Label="Contact Name" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Shipping_Address__c}" rendered="{!bEditMode}"/>  
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Shipping_Address__c}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" /> 
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 2: Technical Contact (if applicable)" collapsible="false" columns="2"  >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Technical_Contact__c}" rendered="{!bEditMode}"/>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Technical_Contact__c}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Title_Technical__c}" rendered="{!bEditMode}"/>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Title_Technical__c}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Phone_Technical__c}" rendered="{!bEditMode}"/>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Phone_Technical__c}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Email_Technical__c}" rendered="{!bEditMode}"/>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Email_Technical__c}" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Previous Page" action="{!page2}"/>   
                <apex:commandButton action="{!doToggleEditMode}" value="Edit" reRender="myPanel" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!doSave}" value="Save" reRender="myPanel" rendered="{!bEditMode}" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="SAVE"/> 
                <apex:commandButton value="PRINT" onclick="window.print();"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

Extension

```
public class SUM {

    public Product_Brief__c pb {get;set;}
    public User u {get;set;}

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}
    public boolean bUpdate {get;set;}
    public string loggedinUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    public User u2 = [Select ContactId From User where Id =: '005R0000001Y6h4'];

    public String ctId{
        get {
         //   if (ctId==null){
         //   if (bUpdate){
                  ctId = u2.ContactId;
         //       }
              return ctId;
         //   }
        }
        set;
    }

    Contact ct = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE id=:ctId];
    public string getacct(){
        Account acct = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE id=:ct.AccountId];  
        return acct.Name;
        return null;
        }

    Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId=:ct.AccountId LIMIT 1];


/* *************** Edit Sec. ************************     */ 

    public Boolean bEditMode {
    get {
      if(bEditMode == null) {
          bEditmode = false;
          }
          return bEditMode;
      }
      set;
    }

    public PageReference doToggleEditMode() {
         bEditMode = !bEditMode;
            return null;
    }

    public PageReference doSave() {
        try {
        // Do your stuff to save your record
        controller.save();
        doToggleEditMode();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        // Handle error
        }

        return null;
        }
/* ********************************************** */

    public PageReference page1(){
    return Page.sumpage1;
    }

    public PageReference page2(){
    return Page.sumpage2;
    }

    public PageReference page3(){
    return Page.sumpage3;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
    controller.save(); 
    return null;
    }

    public SUM(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       this.controller = controller;
    }

}
```

When I click on the save button it will save, but my page will break. It suppose to redirect to the same page. But it does not. Anybody have any idea? Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error: Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page. 

Please email us if you need to get in touch. It will not redirect to the same page and gives me above error.

Comment: @DananjayaPathirana Your save function doesn't redirect. See `return null;`? That means you're explicitly asking to *not* redirect. You could try `return controller.save();` instead.

Comment: @Eric It's a Sites error.

Comment: @sfdcfox - You read my mind...I deleted it just as you were posting....

Comment: You can debug common sites errors by navigating to the page in the full salesforce instance using the url /apex/pagename. Most likely there is an error in your code and viewing the page this way will display the error in more detail

Comment: Ya But it if try return controller.save(); it will take me to another page. But i wan to stay same page that's why i put return null; any idea how to redirect to the same page after saving?

Comment: @DananjayaPathirana Something like `if(controller.save() != null) { PageReference ref = Page.myPage; ref.setRedirect(true); return ref; } return null;`. Return no page reference if an error occurs, or a redirect otherwise.

Comment: @sfdcfox - It works, but i have a problem i want display the values as well. in this case it will redirect to the same page after saving but output values does not show.  Is there any way i can redirect it with  out put values.

Comment: @DananjayaPathirana Well, in that case, your solution is probably okay, but you still have either an error in your code (outside of what's posted), or a permissions issue. You need to debug more.

Comment: Ya Thanks a lot for the help. ill try debugging more.  Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that your Sites user doesn't have permission to do whatever they're trying to do, or they got an exception trying to do it (e.g. NullPointerException in a trigger). See an answer [like this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/debugging-force-com-site-visual-force-pages) on how you can debug these errors. If it's a permissions error, you need to modify the Sites public profile, and if it's an exception, you need to diagnose and fix it, just like any other. There's no way we can help you any more than to generically say that you need to check permissions and exceptions.